# How to retrieve a list of distinct values from a list within a list

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I have a list of objects and in each object they contain a list of ids.

The code below creates a list of 10 members and then creates a list of five random ids in each member.

```
public class Member
{
    List<int> Ids { get; set; }

    public Member()
    {
        Ids = new List<int>();
    }
}

var rnd = new Random();
var container = new List<Member>();

// Add members with random Ids
for ( int i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ){
    var member = new Member();

    for ( int j = 1; j <= 5; j++ ){
        member.Ids.Add( rnd.Next(100) );
    }
}

var distinctIds = ?????;
```

What I'm struggling with is **the LINQ to retrieve a distinct list of the Ids for all members.**

Comment: Just a hint, you're actually just creating 9 members and 4 Ids. Not that it matters for your question :)

Comment: Valid :) I've changed my demo code

Comment: You might get duplicate values in your `for` loop assigning random ids.  Calling `rnd.Next()` in a tight loop may cause duplicates (not sure if that is ok with you but I thought I would point it out).

Comment: @BryanCrosby "Calling rnd.Next() in a tight loop may cause duplicates" - not sure what you're referring to here. Sure, `.Next(int)` might return the same thing on two successive calls (it couldn't really be said to be *random* if a particular value could be guaranteed not to appear), but the tightness of the loop has nothing to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var distinctIds = 
    (from member in container
    from id in member.Ids
    select id).Distinct();
```

There is of course the method-y syntax, which in this case would be using `SelectMany` :

```
var distinctIds = container.SelectMany(member => member.Ids).Distinct();
```

but I can never remember how to call it, so I generally prefer multiple `from`s.

Comment: You can also pass in an IEqualityComparer object to decide how you want that type to be known as distinct... though with integers/strings its default is good enough.